# Cannot exclude module from build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to exclude some modules from my build.gradle file but it(code1 and code2) still downloads the excluded files.

**code 1:**

```
compile (group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.7') {
  exclude group: 'com.amazonaws', module: 'aws-java-sdk-machinelearning'
}
```

**code 2:**

```
  compile (group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.7') {
      exclude module: 'aws-java-sdk-machinelearning'
    }
```

when I tried using the following code,

```
    configurations {
compile.exclude module: 'aws-java-sdk-machinelearning'
}
```

it excludes the files but I don't want to use this method to exclude files

Comment: Which version of gradle are you using? It works well with gradle v. 2.8.

Comment: I'm using Gradle 2.13

Comment: It works with gradle 2.13 as well. Here you have the script: http://pastie.org/10874593

Answer (score 2):

I second/confirm with @Opal that code1 works fine in Gradle 2.13.

What is likely happening is that you have some other (maybe non-aws) dependency, that may be transitively using `aws-java-sdk` which then brings in the machine-learning dependency. Which is why, it works fine when you do a global exclude, but not when you do a local exclude on just `aws-java-sdk`.

Try running `gradlew dependencies --configuration=compile` to get a tree of dependencies, including transitives, to check which dependency might be bringing in `aws-java-sdk-machinelearning`